# Existe algum ação a ser tomada quando existe um comportamento de "caça de reputação/medalhas"?

Tags: debate, suporte, edições-sugeridas

Não vou citar o operador, mas hoje tiveram diversas sugestões de edição na fila de análise que apenas colocavam letras maiúsculas nas frases ou mudava espaçamentos nas revisões.

Eu rejeitei a maior parte delas, classificando as alterações como insuficientes.

Deveria tomar alguma outra ação?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Caçar medalhas é uma função do sistema, a gente é incentivado a fazer isso. O problema é tentar ganhá-las fraudulentamente ou com subterfugios.

Acabo de me topar com uma situação de sugestões de edição aprovadas indevidamente, dei um toque no `@editor` (isso funciona nos comentários) mas o erro é de quem aprovou a edição (e  `@revisor` não funciona) <sup>1</sup>. Não fiz nenhuma "auditoria" mais séria nesse caso, mas quando topamos com situações assim podemos sinalizar o post onde ocorreu isso e informar os moderadores. Eles tem mecanismos para revisar o histórico dos usuários e tomar as medidas necessárias (notificação privada ou suspensão de privilégios).

Quanto ao post incorretamente editado, é só fazer uma reversão ou uma nova edição para corrigir os problemas introduzidos.

<sup>1 (update) A falha do editor normalmente é **não saber** como fazer uma boa edição. Rejeitar suas sugestões lhe manda um sinal de que ele/a precisa melhorar. Aprovar manda o sinal de que está tudo bem. Na minha opinião, a aprovação cega é extremamente daninha, ao site, ao post editado e ao editor novato. **A praga são os *robo-approvers***.</sup>

Comment: "mas o erro é de quem aprovou a edição" +1. É um misto de um querendo rep com edição, e outro querendo medalha com aprovação. E note que geralmente são sempre os mesmos (inclusive alguns que também votam pra fechar e abrir indiscriminadamente, basta aparecer na fila de revisão).

Comment: @Bacco Vale lembrar que rejeitar a edição tb contabiliza as revisões, entretanto muita gente passa o olho e aceita, pois acha que ninguém vai falar nada se aceitar, como se aceitar fosse algo mais natural, enquanto rejeitar pode levantar questionamentos. Entretanto, para a sorte da comunidade, está sendo questionando o erro seja lá se qual foi a ação, aprovação ou rejeição da publicação.

Comment: @Math e além do que você disse, pra rejeitar o pessoal tem que parar pra ler, acho que pra alguns é trabalho demais :D

Comment: @Bacco poisé, para aprovar você aperta só um botão, para rejeitar você tem que apertar um botão, ler as opções, selecionar uma delas e clicar em outro botão. De fato, o caminho mais curto para as valiosíssimas medalhas é aceitando tudo :)

Comment: Também tenho visto muitas edições que não servem para nada.

Comment: Parece então que é hora de ser bastante mais rigoroso por parte da moderação. Não sei se inclusive ativar as "pegadinhas" (review audits)...

Comment: É uma ação muito infantil. Estou nesse fórum desde quando não era aberto ao público em geral e nunca me importei com medalhas. Já estive nessa situação de pessoas corrigindo míseros espaçamentos em meus textos e nem podia rejeitar por não ter reputação necessária.

Comment: @FelipeStoker Você sempre pode aprovar ou rejeitar edições em seus próprios posts (desde que a edição ainda não tenha sido previamente aprovada/rejeitada por outros analistas).

Comment: @FelipeStoker Eu me importo com medalhas, medalhas são legais :D Correção: aqui não é um fórum, é um site de perguntas e respostas.

Comment: @Math mas, uma das definições de fóruns é: "um lugar de perguntas e respostas".

Comment: @FelipeStoker, *não é um fórum* tá no DNA deste software: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/is-stack-overflow-a-forum

Comment: @FelipeStoker um carro tem rodas nem tudo que tem rodas é um carro. Um fórum tem discussões, um site de Q&A não tem. Um fórum pode ter perguntas e respostas mas na prática o formato não incentiva e não organiza desta forma. Por acaso são perguntas e são respostas. Em um Q&A se não for pergunta e resposta, sequer é permitido. Em http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%B3rum_de_discuss%C3%A3o fala de debates. Só estou dando uma definição clara que eu acho que ajudará outras pessoas entenderem a diferença. Eu compreendo o que você quis dizer.

Answer (score 8):

Apenas continue rejeitando.

O autor das modificações está principalmente caçando reputação. Se todos da fila de análise rejeitarem uma edição inválida, vai chegar um hora que o usuário vai perceber que não vai conseguir mais pontuação com esse tipo de ação e provavelmente começará a se esforçar mais para fazer um edição coerente, que é algo benéfico para todos.

Já a caça a medalhas é feita por quem revisa. Esse caso é muito mais difícil de consertar, no SO.com isso é um problema sério e até agora não acharam uma solução satisfatória para isso. Provavelmente o melhor a ser feito é implementarmos as auditorias aqui e começar a mostrar para os analisadores que eles estão errando, se eles persistirem no erro os moderadores podem aplicar alguma punição a eles. Acredito que as auditorias aqui podem surtir um efeito melhor do que no SO.com, já que somos uma comunidade mais compacta e consequentemente é mais fácil administrar tal situação.

Comment: "O autor das modificação" -> "O autor da modificação" rsrsrs

Comment: @DanielOmine valeu ;-) PS: eu sabia o correto, mas na hora de escrever deu algum bug que saiu assim, rs