# Aprovação de edições que não melhoram a pergunta

Tags: debate, filas-de-análise, edições-sugeridas

Relativamente a [esta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20493) edição, se compararem a pergunta antes e depois da edição, nada foi adicionado de novo que tornasse a pergunta mais clara/simples/concreta. Foi uma edição que apenas retirou linhas em branco ao código (o que, dependendo da opinião pessoal, pode dificultar a leitura do código).

A minha questão, será este o tipo de edições que queremos recompensar? Como podemos proceder nestes casos? E o que impede um utilizador de acumular pontos com edições mínimas, quando parece que tudo que aparece na fila de edições sugeridas e aceite?

Comment: Rejeitar, rejeitar, rejeitar...

Comment: Eu deveria ter me atentado a isso quando aceitei. Mea culpa.

Comment: Infelizmente isso vive acontecendo. Eu entendo um erro ou outro, é normal que todo mundo erre em alguma coisa. E muitas vezes o que é erro para um não é para outro. Algumas pessoas aprovam edições ruins sistematicamente. Isto já foi discutido antes. Não contribui para a comunidade. Parece que há o desejo em algumas pessoas de aceitar tudo o que os usuários fazem. Beneficiar o indivíduo em alguns casos vai contra o benefício da comunidade, de uma ampla gama de indivíduos. Há alguns usuários que agem consistentemente assim e até discursam por isto. É triste para a comunidade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Já disse isso antes em [Existe algum ação a ser tomada quando existe um comportamento de “caça de reputação/medalhas”](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1613/201): muito mais que um problema do editor, é um problema do revisor. Inclusive, não sei dizer se é bug ou função, mas `@nomeDoEditor` funciona como notificação nos comentários e `@nomeDoRevisor` não.

Um editor iniciante pode não saber o que exatamente é uma boa edição (ainda que tenha um box amarelo ao lado explicando). A pessoa está ali, feliz, "puxa, posso editar conteúdo aqui", recompensada, "puxa, me dão pontos por isso", reconhecida, "uma medalha!".

Já fiz muita revisão no Stack Overflow, e a maioria das vezes que me dirigi ao @editor apontando porquê a edição aprovada era insuficiente houve *feedback* positivo: "ah, ok, obrigado por avisar, vou ter isso em conta da próxima".

Dirigir-se ao revisor são outros 500 porque você tem que procurar uma pergunta ou resposta da pessoa e fazer um comentário totalmente off-topic e intrometido. E essa pessoa já não é uma iniciante e conhece várias regras do jogo. As estratégias que uso ou já vi em uso:

1. por qualquer motivo, escolhe-se **deixar um comentário** em um post não relacionado: apontar o engano, linkar para referências no Meta e avisar que o comentário é temporário e vai ser removido.
2. tem algo estranho, mas não se fez nenhuma investigação a respeito: abrir uma **pergunta no Meta** pedindo discussão sobre determinada Revisão e tratar somente do problema sem mencionar nem acusar ninguém.
3. tem algo estranho e mais revisões de determinado usuário foram investigadas: se houver outros episódios de aprovações indevidas, **sinalizar qualquer um dos posts** que foi revisado e dar um breve informe da investigação usando a opção `precisa da ♦ atenção do moderador`. A partir daí, o moderador tem ferramentas de comunicação e de suspensão de privilégios que forem necessárias a seu dispor.

Os pontos 1 e 2 podem ser combinados.

Tem uma estratégia à parte que é **rejeitar a edição unilateralmente**:

- **rejeitar a edição** é o recado que os revisores dão ao editor de que precisa melhorar: isso pode ser feito unilateralmente clicando em <kbd>Editar e Rejeitar</kbd>, talvez o *timing* aqui no SOpt não seja importante, mas no SO é melhor fazer isso rapidamente e aplicar outras melhorias de edição na janela de 5 minutos (*grace period*).

Comment: A última nem sempre funciona, infelizmente. É comum ter vários revisores robôs que chegam antes dos que sabem que algo deveria ser rejeitado.

Comment: @bigown, vc já viu por aqui no meta se os *audits* estão ativos? Ou bem qual seria a escala da análise-robô acontecendo aqui...

Comment: Eu lembro que não estava, e pelo que percebo ainda não está. Parece que beta não pode ter *audit*.